# Create new column by grouping a single column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [100, 100, 100, 200, 300, 300, 400],
                    'owner': list('aabbaba')})
 value    owner
  100       a
  100       a
  100       b
  200       b
  300       a
  300       b
  400       a
```

I need to groupby the value column and produce a new output such that no duplicates exist in the `value` column. A value that is linked to both a and b should have an `owner` value of `both` while a value with only a single owner should just have that owner.

Output desired:

```
value    owner
 100     both
 200     b
 300     both
 400     a
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is cheking the amount of unique values within each group, and use `np.where` to replace with either `both` or the unique value contained in a group:

```
import numpy as np

out = df.groupby('value', as_index=False).agg({'owner':'nunique'})
out['owner'] = np.where(out.owner.eq(2), 
                        'both', 
                        df.groupby('value').owner.first())
```

---

```
print(out)

   value owner
0    100  both
1    200     b
2    300  both
3    400     a
```